SQLite Join 2 tables with table1 having two columns that reference table2
I have two tables:
jobs
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jobs (
    job_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    job_name TEXT,
    prime_desc INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES descriptions(desc_id),
    scnd_desc INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES descriptions(desc_id),
);

INSERT INTO jobs (job_name, prime_desc, scnd_desc) VALUES ('Soldier', 1, 5);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_name, prime_desc, scnd_desc) VALUES ('Pastor', 2, 3);
INSERT INTO jobs (job_name, prime_desc, scnd_desc) VALUES ('Firefighter', 5, 4);

descriptions
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS descriptions (
    desc_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    desc_name TEXT,
);

INSERT INTO descriptions (desc_name) VALUES ('Strong');
INSERT INTO descriptions (desc_name) VALUES ('Pious');
INSERT INTO descriptions (desc_name) VALUES ('Honest');
INSERT INTO descriptions (desc_name) VALUES ('Agile');
INSERT INTO descriptions (desc_name) VALUES ('Brave');

In this example, I would like to be able to add two descriptions to a job. The code works and I can query it:
SELECT * FROM jobs;

This returns the expected result:
1|Soldier|1|5
2|Pastor|2|3
3|Firefighter|5|4

What I have been trying to do is get a query that lists the job name and the primary and secondary description names:
Firefighter|Brave|Agile

I have not been able to get that result.
I have tried:
SELECT
    jobs.job_name,
    desc.desc_name
FROM
    jobs
JOIN
    descriptions ON jobs.prime_desc = descriptions.desc_id
JOIN
    descriptions ON jobs.scnd_desc = descriptions.desc_id;

This returns an error:
Parse error: ambiguous column name: descriptions.desc_name
  SELECT jobs.job_name, descriptions.desc_name FROM jobs JOIN descriptions ON...
          error here ---^

I searched the Internet on that error and couldn't find anything that is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.
I tried many different combinations of:
RIGHT JOIN, LEFT JOIN, UNION, UNION ALL, ALIAS

in multiple configurations. The closest I came is with UNION, but it did not output the results as desired; here's the UNION I tried:
SELECT
    jobs.job_name, descriptions.desc_name
FROM
    jobs
JOIN
    descriptions ON jobs.prime_desc = descriptions.desc_id
UNION
SELECT
    jobs.job_name, descriptions.desc_name
FROM
    jobs
JOIN
    descriptions ON jobs.scnd_desc = descriptions.desc_id;

This returns:
Soldier|Strong
Pastor|Pious
Firefighter|Brave
Soldier|Brave
Pastor|Honest
Firefighter|Agile

It's returning the results as asked, so I know it's something I'm doing wrong. I just don't know what it is that I'm doing that won't print the results in one line per job, as illustrated by the Firefighter example above.
I've tried creating a column alias, a table alias, et al. I'm at a loss as to how to approach this. Any help is appreciated.

You can not join the same table twice or more, so use Aliases, so that the database understands, what you want
SELECT
    jobs.job_name,
    desc1.desc_name
  ,desc2.desc_name
FROM
    jobs
JOIN
    descriptions desc1 ON jobs.prime_desc = desc1.desc_id
JOIN
    descriptions desc2 ON jobs.scnd_desc = desc3.desc_id;


This is exactly what I needed, thank you! I was missing the correct SELECT and was misapplying the aliases in the JOIN sections.

You reference the table description twice, so you need to assign each reference a unique alias.

Thank you for the reply. Where would I do that? I tried:
SELECT jobs.job_name, descriptions.desc_name FROM jobs JOIN descriptions ON jobs.prime_desc = descriptions.desc_id JOIN descriptions AS d ON jobs.prime_desc = d.desc_id;
And that did not return the expected results; it only listed the first descriptions
